# Hide div not works in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This is my code. it work perfect in chrome and firefox but not in ie8. i have test in ie10 and ie11 . it works.. do you know how to fix this?.. i get the code from here : https://jsfiddle.net/XqshE/2/, Does it because of this tag?..`getElementsByClassName` not supported by IE8?

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showhide(id){
        if (document.getElementById) {
          var divid = document.getElementById(id);
          var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
          for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
             divs[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          divid.style.display = "block";
        } 
        return false;
 }


 </script>


<style>
.bio_image {
    display:inline-block;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div onclick="showhide('bill');" class="bio_image"><div class="name">Bill Murray</div></div>
<div onclick="showhide('bill2');" class="bio_image"><div class="name">Bill Murray</div></div>
<div onclick="showhide('bill3');" class="bio_image"><div class="name">Bill Murray</div></div>
<div class="hide" id="bill">BILL</div>
<div class="hide" id="bill2">BILL2</div>
<div class="hide" id="bill3">BILL3</div>
```

Comment: in short `yes` because of `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: do you know how to change my code?

Comment: you want it to work in `ie 8` or `ie 7` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` functions of jQuery. modify your function as below

```
<script>
function showhide(id){
     $('#'+id).show();
     $('#'+id).siblings('.hide').hide();   
 }
 </script>
```

**[API Document for siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**

Comment: hai.. this works like charm.. i just wanna ask why all my div position become below as i put <br /> . in ff or chrome.. it should be single line.. in IE it become 3 line of div

Comment: `<br/>` is used for break line, hence it will shift element after `<br/>` in next line

Comment: i want it be single line horizontal  like ie and ff..  in ie8 it become vertical instead of horizontal. can you spot why?

Comment: remove `<br/>` and use `<span>` inside `<div>` like `<div><spanclass="hide" id="bill">BILL</span>
<spanclass="hide" id="bill2">BILL2</span>
<spanclass="hide" id="bill3">BILL3</span></div>` as `<div>` moves to next line

Comment: i have problems with Bill Murray not bill 1,2,3.. the Bill Murray become vertical in IE8

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` method is not supported by IE8.

You should use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` (works in IE8+) or a library that implements that functionality - like:

- `jQuery`
- `Moo Tools`
- `DOJO`
- `YUI`
- `Prototype`

  ... Among others...

---

`querySelectorAll` support:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13

`getElementsByClassName` support:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
function showhide(id){
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
        for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        divid.style.display = "block";
    } 
    return false;
}
```

with

```
function showhide(id){
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('#'+id).show();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to add a mouseover effect on this script? So that when you mouse over the images, it will also show the hidden div. if you mouse out, it will hide the div.

But still when you click on the image, it will show the hidden div. (how it works now)

I just want to add the option of showing the hidden divs during mouseover/mouseout as well.

Thank you.